# Do I have a chance at an academic career in North America or Europe?

Tags: career-path, tenure-track, productivity

I have two masters, topped both of them, and published articles that have been widely cited, though they date before 2013. I am struggling with my PhD because of a lack of support from the faculty and funds. I have been too busy surviving after that. What can I do to maximize my chances of an academic career in Europe or North America? Is my age a crucial factor?

Comment: There's a chance this will be closed as opinion-based. Could you rephrase so that the question focuses on something more operational and/or narrow? E.g. how can I maximize my chances for program X with my particular resumé? How important is age or time-to-submission? How important is a gap in publications? etc. (Some of these questions already have answers on this site.)

Answer (score 3):

My answer to this question of yours [Does the time taken to do a PhD affect post doctoral applications?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102281/does-the-time-taken-to-do-a-phd-affect-post-doctoral-applications/102282) does also apply here: There is a chance, yes. How high that chance is depends on many factors. Your age, your publications, etc. are some of them, but others are for example the quality of your work, the availability of the position you are looking for, the energy you put into applying (e.g. do you contact every last university in all of North America and Europe?), what you want as a "career"  - e.g. are you happy with a postdoc position that is not limited, or do you want to get to dean of the department before you hit 60 - etc.

So yes, there is a chance and yes, it is somewhat lowered by the points you gave. If you want to take it or not is your choice, no one else can make it for you.